# Difference of for next in and while read line

Tags: bash

Suppose file is

value1.1    value2.1
value1.2    value2.2
..

Why is it that:

while read line
do
value1=$(echo "$line" | cut -f1)
done < file

works as intended, but:


for next in $(cat file)
do
value1=$(echo "$next" | cut -f1)
done

Does not. What's the fundamental difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` performs word splitting, taking each word in turn from the text separated by any character in `$IFS`. `read` reads using `\n` as a delimiter, which causes it to read an entire line at a time.

Comment: Ah, so it's as easy as setting IFS="\n" to get read like behavior from for. Edit, apparently not..

Comment: Or you could just do the right thing in the first place and use `while read`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. For future reference, setting IFS to \n does work, I just had wrong syntax above. It's IFS=$'\n'

Comment: Yeah, you're right. while read is actually far better way to do it. [ref1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) [ref2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)